# How to find a date in sql of previous 10 year first day of year to todays date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I writing a query where I need to get a data from last 10 year i.e. (01/01/2009) to todays (07/04/2019). But the query I have written is returning the date 07/04/2009.

This is my code that I have written:

```
(SELECT DATEADD(YEAR,-10,GETDATE()))
```

How can I make it work so it can return date of 01/01/2009 to today's date.

```
(SELECT DATEADD(YEAR,-10,GETDATE()))
```

I expect to get the result 01/01/2009 to 07/04/2019

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of date from parts function as well.

```
select dateadd(year, -10, datefromparts(year(getdate()),1,1))
```

Output:

```
2009-01-01
```

Comment: Sorry. didn't see your datefromparts()  +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Always nice as expected ;-)

Comment: Yeah, they do sometimes, but we should be nice @JohnCappelletti ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT GETDATE(),  -- current date
 DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, DATEADD(YEAR,-10,GETDATE())), 0) -- 1st day of year 10 years ago
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=58e31f3a662c0bfd66273f8c28a3814d)**